# Javascript Canvas refresh flicker

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am writing a basic chess gui in html5/javascript and I have a question on how to avoid the flicker when I redraw the canvas control.  Basically I am drawing the chess pieces from a 2D array and every time I redraw the array, I clear the canvas which creates a slight flicker.  What would be the best way to avoid this?  Thank you in advance, Dave.

```
//Array of chess pieces
var PieceArray = ["Null", "WhiteKing", "WhiteQueen", "WhiteKnight", "WhiteBishop", "WhiteRook", "WhitePawn", "BlackKing", "BlackQueen", "BlackKnight", "BlackBishop", "BlackRook", "BlackPawn"]

//Current state of the chess pieces on the board
var BoardArray = [[11, 9, 10, 8, 7, 10, 9, 11],
                  [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
                  [5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5]];

//Param1: Image Url
//Param2: X position
//Param3: Y position
function Draw(image, x, y) {
    var can = document.getElementById('ChessBoard');
    var context = can.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = 'Sprites/' + image + ".png";
    imageObj.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y);
    };
}

//Function that draws the chess pieces to the canvas
function DrawPieces() {
    var array2;
    for (var i = 0; i < BoardArray.length; i++) {
        array2 = BoardArray[i];
        for (var x = 0; x < array2.length; x++) {
            if (array2[x] != "Null") {
                Draw(PieceArray[array2[x]], x * 70, i * 70);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but I'm guessing the flickering is not caused by the redraw. Your Draw function actually tries to get the sprite image every frame, so the flickering is probably from the delay you get from downloading the image. Try to store imageObj as a globally accessible variable and load it only once. Use if (imageObj) {context.drawImage(imageobj, x, y)} instead of imageObj.onload.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: if (imageObj) would not work. Do something that ensures imageObj is loaded when you draw it in the Draw function. Maybe set a flag in onload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work? (not tested)

```
//Array of chess pieces
var PieceArray = ["Null", "WhiteKing", "WhiteQueen", "WhiteKnight", "WhiteBishop", "WhiteRook", "WhitePawn", "BlackKing", "BlackQueen", "BlackKnight", "BlackBishop", "BlackRook", "BlackPawn"]

var PieceImages = {};

//Current state of the chess pieces on the board
var BoardArray = [[11, 9, 10, 8, 7, 10, 9, 11],
                  [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
                  [5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5]];

//Param1: Image Url
//Param2: X position
//Param3: Y position
function Draw(image, x, y) {
    var can = document.getElementById('ChessBoard');
    var context = can.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

    if (PieceImages[image]) {
        if (PieceImages[image].complete) {
            context.drawImage(PieceImages[image], x, y);
        }
    }
    else {
        PieceImages[image] = new Image();
        PieceImages[image].src = 'Sprites/' + image + ".png";
    }
}

//Function that draws the chess pieces to the canvas
function DrawPieces() {
    var array2;
    for (var i = 0; i < BoardArray.length; i++) {
        array2 = BoardArray[i];
        for (var x = 0; x < array2.length; x++) {
            if (array2[x] != "Null") {
                Draw(PieceArray[array2[x]], x * 70, i * 70);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing unnecessary re-loading and DOM look-ups. The reloading of the image will be the cause in this case as the image may not be able to decode and get ready before you draw it.

Cache those things outside your draw method and it should work:

```
var can = document.getElementById('ChessBoard');
var context = can.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function () {
    /// start you loop/logic here instead...
    DrawPieces()
};
imageObj.src = 'Sprites/' + image + ".png";

function Draw(image, x, y) {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y);
}

//Function that draws the chess pieces to the canvas
function DrawPieces() {

    /// also move clear here or none of the pieces but
    /// the last will show
    context.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

    var array2;
    for (var i = 0; i < BoardArray.length; i++) {
        array2 = BoardArray[i];
        for (var x = 0; x < array2.length; x++) {
            if (array2[x] != "Null") {
                Draw(PieceArray[array2[x]], x * 70, i * 70);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that when the image has loaded *then* you go to next step (loop or input logic etc.).